# How to make my vb.net app run from a single USB drive only?

Tags: vb.net

I've developed an application in vb.net that can run from a usb drive. But i need my app to work only from that usb in which i distribute it.

If someone copies it to other Drive/USB, it must not work. Do u know how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get a serial number/identical id from the drive you installed it to and configure your application to check against that id on startup.

There is an article about getting the serial number of a USB drive here: http://www.cfdan.com/posts/Retrieving_Non-Volatile_USB_Serial_Number_Using_C_Sharp.cfm

Comment: If you are distributing your application on USB drives, this answer is probably what you are looking for!